# Rails app only pointing to default rails index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, capistrano, unicorn, ubuntu-12.04

So I am new to deploying to an Ubuntu Server (12.04). I have nginx and unicorn installed. Everything seems to be working except for the fact that I don't know how to point it to my app. Currently I am pointing to 'home/administrator/apps/my_site/current/public' however all my files are in 'home/administrator/apps/my_site/app/views/'. I am currently only pointing to the static files like the error htmls and the default rails index.html. How do I get nginx to point to my views/app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Nginx + Unicorn then you don't point Nginx at any path, you run up unicorn on the server and then have Nginx proxy all it's requests to the unicorn instance. I would recommend looking at using foreman and then it's `foreman export upstart` which exports ubuntu upstart scripts for controlling unicorn.

[This](http://sleekd.com/general/configuring-nginx-and-unicorn/) link gives you details on how to config your nginx site.